# Simplifying boolean algebra (XOR)

Tags: boolean, digital

[image]

[image]

I know how to convert first and second term to the first term of the simplified expression, but I don't know how to convert the rest.

By simplifying, I can get rid of A_Bar in the third term and A in the fifth term and get =B*C_bar

How is it that B*C_bar + the fourth term = becomes XOR(B,C) ?

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions are clearly the same. This can be easily proven by truth tables.
The first one is:
[image]
And the second one:
[image]

However, this does not fully answer your question.

> B*C_bar + the fourth term = becomes XOR(B,C)

This is clearly true if A is true, since per definitionem, `B XOR C = B_bar and C OR B and C_bar`.
If A is false, these terms are always false and you cannot simplify these two to B XOR C! They are not equal!

[image]

Note: Tables generated with http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/
Note2: ^= OR, ¬ = NOT, ∨ = AND

Answer (score 0):

let play a game.
Let a=not(A), b=not(B) and c=not(C) and *=xor

**Y = ab + (B*C)**

Y = ab + Bc + bC

Y = ab(1) + Bc(1) + bC(1)

Y = ab(c+C) + Bc(a+A) + bC(a+A)

Y = abc + abC + Bca + BcA + bCa + bCA

Y = abc + abC + aBc + ABc + abC + AbC

**Y = abc + abC + aBc + ABc + AbC**

That is the first equ.

Comment: Please, tell me if it is understandable, or if you prefer I write this in other way.